# Postgres matching to nearest time

Tags: postgresql

I have two datasets that I am trying to join using psql (9.3.5) on Ubuntu:

The first set is contains information on an arrival time at node j, after leaving node i. I am trying to match this against the nearest scheduled arrival time at j and then calculate the difference in distance (d) between i and j for that scheduled event. This difference varies depending on the schedule.

My current attempt involves a two joins (on i and j) between the first (raw) table and the schedule (to_match) table, and using min() to return the difference between the event time and the schedule.

```
        select r.i, r.j, r.time, second.schedule, 
min((r.time - second.schedule)) as diff_from_schedule, 
    round(second.d - first.d) as d_diff
    from raw r
    inner join to_match first on r.i = first.key
    inner join to_match second on r.j = second.key
    group by r.i, r.j, r.time, second.schedule, d_diff
```

This does not return the nearest/minimum difference between the values. In fact, some are quite far off.

```
i           j           time    sched   diff_from_schedule  d_diff
12598       14013       57233   20340   36893   2951
12598       14013       25829   26640   811     3015
12598       14013       53927   66780   12853   2951
12598       14013       66236   18180   48056   2951
```

Also, there are 24 records in the raw table, but it returns every value in the to_match table. I am using inner joins, should it not return only records from the left table? Does anyone have an idea?

A PGDump with sample data is in this [Gist]{https://gist.github.com/laidig/37fcd396009cabf5c1e8}. Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an intractable problem here because your data does not allow to derive a singular solution. First the closest "solution", but read on for details:

```
SELECT DISTINCT diffs.*, round(dest.d - src.d) AS d_diff
FROM
   (SELECT DISTINCT ON (r.i, r.j, r.time)
      r.i, r.j, r.time, dest.schedule, min(abs(r.time - dest.schedule)) AS diff
    FROM raw r
    JOIN to_match dest ON r.j = dest.key
    GROUP BY r.i, r.j, r.time, dest.schedule
    ORDER BY r.i, r.j, r.time, diff ASC) AS diffs
JOIN to_match dest ON dest.key = diffs.j AND dest.schedule = diffs.schedule
JOIN to_match src ON src.key = diffs.i
ORDER BY diffs.i, diffs.j, diffs.time
```

The sub-query calculates for every combination of `raw` data and `to_match` schedules the minimum time difference and then selects the record with the best match for each `raw` record. The outer query then adds the `d_diff` to it.

You have a deficiency in your data model, though. For each `key` value in the `to_match` table you have two `d` values. For `j` that is not a problem because you can filter on the `schedule` value, but you don't have that information for `i`, hence you get two hits for every record of `raw` data (or as many as you have distinct `d` values for the `i` value). The above is therefore the best possible outcome.

You probably want to analyze your data model more carefully and normalize `to_match` to at least 1 more table, adding more information on the schedules such that you can uniquely match both `i` and `j` to a schedule.

Comment: ahah. I was trying to whittle down this the most possible, but I have another key (trips between i and j) that I can use. With your answer I'm on a much better track! Thanks!